# Как определять тип маршрутизации событий? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть пузырьковые, туннелируемые, прямые события. Вопрос в том, как определять к какому типу относится рандомно взятое событие, например textchanged или keyup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пузырьковые с туннелируемыми ходят парами. С префиксом `Preview` - tunneling, без префикса - bubbling. Например:

- `PreviewMouseDown` (tunneling) и `MouseDown` (bubbling)
- `PreviewMouseWheel` (tunneling) и `MouseWheel` (bubbling)

Для всего остального нужно курить [доки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590079.aspx)